# requests.exceptions.SSLError in Py Script

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

Earlier this month, I wrote python code that worked, but today, I am having this error:

> requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=6543): Max retries exceeded with url: /tptenv (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1002)')))

This is readygosetup.py:

```
import ssl
import sys
import requests

baseurl = "https://127.0.0.1:6543/"

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Usage: python readygosetup.py <envname>")
    sys.exit(1)

envname = sys.argv[1]

if not envname:
    print("Error: Both arguments are required.")
    print("Usage: python readygosetup.py <envname>")
    sys.exit(1)

print("╔════════════╣ ReadyGoSetup ╠═════════════╗\n"
      "║                                         ║\n"
      "║    An App For Auto-Setting Up Envs!     ║\n"
      "║         Made Proudly in India,          ║\n"
      "║        To Be Used By The World.         ║\n"
      "║                                         ║\n"
      "╚═════════════════════════════════════════╝\n")

print("|+- Trying To Connect To URL...")

urlcode = requests.get(baseurl + envname, verify=ssl.CERT_NONE)

try:
    urlcode = requests.get(baseurl + envname)
    print("|+- Successfully Connected To URL!")
    pass
except:
    print("|+- Something Has Gone Wrong! Exiting...")
    exit(1)
print("|+- Trying To Get Env Code...")
try:
    envcode = urlcode.text
except:
    print("|+- Something Has Gone Wrong! Exiting...")
print("|+- Successfully Got Env Code!")
print("|+- Switching Over To Code Output...\n")
print("════════════ CODE OUTPUT ════════════"
exec(envcode)
```

I thought that it will execute the code obtained from webserver `rgs-server.py` will be run on the host machine.

I tried to update python, I also tried to use `pip --upgrade requests`.

**Edit:**

To fix the problem, I just had to change the url with `http://` instead of `https://`

Comment: Please Don't Write With All Words Capitalized Like This. It Is Very Annoying To Read Text Like That.